# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::method() error in laravel 5

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting an error when i click the delete button which calls  `Controller@delete` method on a controller.

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::destroy()
>
> throw new BadMethodCallException("Call to undefined method
>   {$className}::{$method}()");

destroy method

```
public function destroy($id)
{
     User::where('role', 'admin')->destroy($id);
     return redirect('/home')->with('message', 'Deleted!');
}
```

Comment: Try: `User::find($id)->delete();` Hope this fixed it!

Comment: @HirenGohel sorry i forgot to include the where('role', 'admin') part. that part is actually causing error.

Comment: Try: `$user = User::where('role', 'admin')->where('id', $id); $user->delete();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::delete()` can be used only on `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` instance. When you use `where()` you get `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`. That's the reason why you're getting error. Use `->delete()` instead `->destroy()` and it will work fine!

Comment: you mean `destroy` can only be used on the model as a static call? i think that is a typo `delete` -> `destroy`

Answer (score 2):

First find the record from DB, like:

```
$user = User::where('role', 'admin')->where('id', $id);
```

And then delete it, like:

```
$user->delete();
```

Hope this will fixed your issue!!

Answer (score 1):

You only can destroy an existing model using key. If you want filters then use delete instead.

**laravel docs:**

`Deleting An Existing Model By Key`

```
User::destroy(1);

User::destroy(array(1, 2, 3));

User::destroy(1, 2, 3);
```

`Of course, you may also run a delete query on a set of models:`

```
$affectedRows = User::where('votes', '>', 100)->delete();
```